# How to run a file on background using vbscript with launch options

Tags: vbscript

I need to run a batch file in the background with launch option "1" (so it will %1 in the batch file).
here is my code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to quote strings, and - optionally - a sub to map all elements of an array via a manipulator function to build command lines in a structured/well scaling way; use Join() to put the parts together (with automagical space separator):

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Sub mapF(a, f)
  Dim i
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      a(i) = f(a(i))
  Next
End Sub

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = "C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat"
Dim aParms : aParms = Split("1#/pi:pa po#last parm", "#")
mapF aParms, GetRef("qq")

Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
    qq(sFSpec) _
  , Join(aParms) _
))

WScript.Echo qq(sCmd)
```

output:

```
cscript startaudio.vbs
""C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat" "1" "/pi:pap po" "last parm""
```

Comment: @OttoLaakkonen - "doesn't work" doesn't work (as a description of a problem)

Comment: After the message it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @OttoLaakkonen - why should it? There is no .Run statement in my demo (building the command) script.

Comment: Oh I am a one big derp. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The script you ask is as follows:

```
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat " & objArgs(0), 0, false)
```

Save it for example as ***myscript.vbs***.

Note that the parameter ***0*** in the code means that the window will be hidden. The paremeter ***false*** in the code means that the excution of the ***.vbs*** will not wait for the ***.bat*** to finish.

What will happen is that, the .vbs will start the .bat and finish its execution, leaving the .bat being executed in the background, as you request.

Exeucute it like this:

```
c:\<whatever>\wscript myscript.vbs <the_parameter>
```