# VBS run not working

Tags: vbscript

I am a noob with vbs, here is a script (from [How to run a file on background using vbscript with launch options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694670/how-to-run-a-file-on-background-using-vbscript-with-launch-options)). But the run doesn't work.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Sub mapF(a, f)
  Dim i
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      a(i) = f(a(i))
  Next
End Sub

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = "C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat"
Dim aParms : aParms = Split("1#/pi:pa po#last parm", "#")
mapF aParms, GetRef("qq")

Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
    qq(sFSpec) _
  , Join(aParms) _
))

WshShell.Run qq(sCmd)
```

Comment: Looks to me when you go to run it you are adding additional quotes to the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qq(sCmd)` is returning This :

> ""C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat" "1" "/pi:pa po" "last parm""

You want :

> "C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat" "1" "/pi:pa po" "last parm"

Remove the `qq(sCmd)` function and it should work.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Sub mapF(a, f)
  Dim i
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      a(i) = f(a(i))
  Next
End Sub

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = "C:\Program Files\Pineapplesoft\Lost computer\lostcomputeraudio.bat"
Dim aParms : aParms = Split("1#/pi:pa po#last parm", "#")
mapF aParms, GetRef("qq")

Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
    qq(sFSpec) _
  , Join(aParms) _
))

wshShell.Run sCmd
```

Comment: And what should I add to make it run on background?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx. You can try wshShell.Run sCmd, 0, False according to the attached article the window should be hidden.

Answer (score -1):

You can run Cmd like this

```
Set shell=CreateObject
Shell.Run("cmd.exe")
```

Comment: No, you can't. And even with the proper arg to CreateObject, running `cmd.exe` makes no sense.